# Are H1-B and J-1 questions going to be migrated to Expats?

Tags: discussion, immigration-questions, migration

Now that Expats.SE is open-beta, will expat related questions be migrated there or will they stay on Travel.SE?

For example I've noted that bunch of questions just got tagged as [h1b-visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/h1b-visas) and [j1-visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/j1-visas). Will these get migrated?

Comment: I added those tags because I noticed that they were specific kinds of visas that came up frequently enough. I'd added a tag for b1/b2 visas a while back.

Comment: Not all questions tagged such are off-topic here. Of those that are off-topic here, closed, and not of sucky quality, I think we probably should try migrating at least on to expats.SE to see how it goes. Good practice for both sites.

Answer (score 1):

People generally get visas because they intend to travel. Most questions currently tagged [h1b-visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/h1b-visas) or [j1-visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/j1-visas) fall in two categories:

- Travelling, usually passing a border, with a visa. Such questions are completely on-topic here, no matter what the visa status here (tourist, student, work, permanent resident, national, …). [[1]](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13337/new-h1b-arrival-what-do-i-need-for-the-port-of-entry) [[3]](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16503/h1b-enter-us-through-guam) [[4]](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17015/is-it-safe-to-cross-the-canadian-border-with-a-j1-visa-and-come-back-on-a-b1-vis) [[8]](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19854/amex-travel-insurance-for-h1b-visa-holder) [[12]](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24114/usa-philippines-flight-via-toronto-with-us-j1-visa)
- Questions about mixing short-term and long-term visas and activities. Just because a long-term visa is involved doesn't make them off-topic. (Consider the symmetric case: short-term-visa.SE would reject the question as involving a long term visa, long-term-visa.SE would reject the question as involving a short term visa.) [[2]](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14417/i-had-a-j1-trainee-can-i-go-to-canada-and-come-back-with-an-esta) [[5]](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17089/from-j1-to-esta-the-same-year) [[6]](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17172/traveling-to-the-us-on-the-vwp-before-entering-with-a-j1-visa) [[7]](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18320/can-a-non-us-citizen-living-in-the-us-on-a-j1-visa-travel-to-cuba) [[11]](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23694/can-you-change-from-a-j1-visa-to-an-esta-by-going-to-mexico-for-a-few-weeks)

Only **off-topic** questions should be migrated. Not questions that happen to be also on-topic elsewhere.

That leaves only two questions [[9]](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22445/j1-visa-applying-for-canadian-student-visa) [[10]](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22489/two-passports-one-with-j1-visa) which are about obtaining a long-term visa and thus may be off-topic (but that's an issue we've never had consensus on).

Comment: For clarity, both H-1B and J-1 are work visas, not travel visas.

Comment: @vartec “Travel visa” isn't a standard term, but it seems strange to me to reserve the term to a subset of the visas that allow their holder to travel. If you want to enter the US the US to work, you need a J1 visa (or one of a few other documents). It's a document that you need to travel (a travel visa) as well as a document that you need to work (a work visa).

Comment: You're effectively saying that anything related to crossing border is on-topic on Travel.SE. IMO it seems like [boat programming](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/what-is-the-boat-programming-meme-about).

Comment: @vartec Uh? Yes, crossing a border is traveling. This has nothing to do with “boat programming” — that's something like “how do I edit my code while crossing a border” which is not about crossing a border nor otherwise about traveling.

Comment: @vartec: work visas are not opposed to travel visas, they are opposed to tourist visas. Both tourism travel and work travel are travel.

Comment: @hippietrail: IMO relocation and travelling are different things, even though relocation does include traveling from point A to point B, maybe even crossing borders.

Comment: @vartec: Nope relocation is a kind of travelling or involves travelling. Any time you move from point A to point B you're travelling. Relocation is different to holidaying or vacationing though. Right now I'm looking for cheap tickets to travel back home after my 7 or 8 month trip around Asia.